# Powershell Impersonation: Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Using Powershell V2

I'm having the following issue when attempting to impersonate an admin user within a Powershell script. The functionality of the script is to copy a file from a server location to the users C:\Program Files drive. However the users "C:\Program Files" is locked down to the user so this has to be performed by an admin.

Here's what I've tried

1. In a Powershell script set up user impersonation passing in the details of an admin user via:

   $returnValue = [Import.Win32]::LogonUser($Username, $Domain, $Password, 2, 0, [ref]$tokenHandle)
2. Within the same script I then call the file copy command

   Copy-Item -Path "\server\location\file.txt" -Destination "C:\Program Files\"

The script always fails with **Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid.**

Am I doing something incorrect? Is what I'm attempting even possible or has anyone else got any idea's on an approach to solve this task?

**Synopsis**: Run a powershell script on a user PC within which I impersonate an admin user to perform a file copy ??

Comment: maybe this helps: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Impersonate-a-User-9bfeff82

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the `-credential` parameter on `Copy-Item`?